# How to give the type of number that is not zero?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I had a hard time trying to define the type of `Result` like:

`Result` should be one of the following patterns

```
type Result<Some> = { code: 0; some_result: ...}
// or
type Result = { code: NonZero; message: string}
```

How to make this get typed?

Maybe this question can be divided into:

1. implement `NonZero` (p.s. `Exclude<number, 0>` does not work)
2. give typing to the generic `Result`

---

#### Updates

I wrote a working snippet as following:

```
type Result<TCode extends number, T extends {} = {}> = TCode extends 0
  ? { code: 0; } & T
  : { code: TCode; reason: string };

type SomeResult = {some_result: string}

function getSomeResult(): Result<0 | -1 | 6007 | 114514, SomeResult> {
  return {
    code: 0,
    some_result: ''
  }
}

const result = getSomeResult()

switch (result.code) {
  case 0:
    // this is wrong: reason should be void
    result.reason
    // this is ok:
    result.some_result
    break
  default:
    // this is ok: there's always a reason when code is non-zero
    result.reason
}
```

Now TS compiler can infer the other property is void, however I need to write down all possible non-zeros for `code` as type parameter.

How to type `NonZero`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAYQPYBNoQA9gIA7HeKExAWwCMIAnAPigF4oAGKQ4si7PACgoUAPxQA3lADGuCAC5OAbijws1CAH0GCFMEXxgDAJYkA5lAC+wqIqmy8igRBUb48AIZmFqo6YuWSoKCoJBQGB7wEACMbLC6qGgcTEGh0BFRAExxcEiJ0SmCQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am i missing?

Comment: @wonderflame I think he also wants this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAYQPYBNoQA9gIA7HeKExAWwCMIAnKAXigAYA+F9qQ4sitjwAoKFAD8UAN5QAxrggAudgG4o8LNQgB9BghTBl8YAwCWJAOZQAvqKjKZ8vMqEQ1W+PACGFpepPmVtYqwsKgkFAYXvAQbNxwSKgh4dBRMQCM8fqoaJzJ4KnREABMWYno6RwhQA

Comment: I've played for a bit with it, I don't think you can do that. I would recommend using same approach as most NodeJS API have - error and result, you check if error is empty - then result must exist, etc. Or take a look at https://github.com/peterboyer/esresult

Comment: type SomeResult = {some_result: string}
type SomeReason = {reason: string}

type Result<TCode extends number, T extends SomeResult | SomeReason> = TCode extends 0
  ? { code: 0; } & Exclude<T, SomeReason>
  : { code: TCode} & Exclude<T, SomeResult>;

function getSomeResult(): Result<0 | -1 | 6007 | 114514, SomeResult | SomeReason> {
  return {
    code: 0,
    some_result: ''
  } 
}

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to type `number` without zero, but this  attempts to follow closely your syntax. It just adds a cast to disambiguate the union type in the switch statement.

```
type Result<TCode extends number, T extends {} = {}> = TCode extends 0
  ? { code: 0; } & T
  : { code: TCode; reason: string };

type SomeResult = {some_result: string}

function getSomeResult(): Result<0, SomeResult> | Result<number> {
  if (Math.random()<0.5){
    return {
      code: 0,
      some_result: ''
    };
  }
  else {
    return {
      code: Math.floor(Math.random()+1),
      reason:""
    };
  }
}
function cast<T>(x:any): asserts x is T {}
const result = getSomeResult()
switch (result.code) {
  case 0:
    cast<Result<0,SomeResult>>(result);
    // this is wrong: reason should be void
    result.reason
    // this is ok:
    result.some_result
    break
  default:
    cast<Result<number>>(result);
    // this is ok: there's always a reason when code is non-zero
    result.reason
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQMIHsAm0EAHsBAHZ7xRmIC2ARhAE4A0UGUxpFVA3gL5QAvFAEA+Ye1wFOJcpSgAGAFBQoAflFQAxvggAuJQG4oggGTtVUQ7x17D2PSaYQAhvBxlD8YEwCWZADmpkbKyqCQUADKOLQQcEiokrwecQD6LonA3r4BgfxhAGaIZNrAfp5QgRDAMXEJKMAAFACUhg2oaIpsdfEIjRIAPrD9nTQMzBK8Vn6FUE0Asq7AABYAdEyuFLGtXWsArC3TamouwIhMZKJWJ3YEht03J6kQGaPZUADkn0-8oWoFNQQZDwaDHE5nC5XcG3XT3KBLVZrQrIHA4JiLZbrTbbWitADUAEYWiwnqc3B4vAAiKm-f6mZQFYqlcqVbTudAYMRNIj6LYgNpQdygpjAKhEKB+KgcATKXRkHxQTKNSTVWqxPpZVrKeAAdz8wG0K3mytQazhEBa1zU7NBSn0T1t6A66G6vRdYm5puALXpagA9P6oKspZKqLqmJ5AoYXO5KvAVjgUHgoIwoAA3HB+PBPb0bCmeJ6B4MrUOhnAAawdtzzLzeWSe9FjFasBEKrka1ZOTrQLrQ40YTE9TW9vqLQZDVHLVZLzAgnyormQutcIEXSoLV11K3Id2gobIngAtAAvZg4XPvfNxsiM5RAA)

The standard TypeScript compiler friendly way would typically add a kind field to disambiguate, then a cast wouldn't be necessary.

```
type ResultNormal<T> = {
   kind: "normal";
} & T;
type ResultAbnormal = { 
   kind: "abnormal";
   code: TCode; reason: string 
};
function getSomeResult(): 
  ResultNormal<{some_result: string}> | ResultAbnormal {
  ...
}
```

Then you can switch on `kind`.

Comment: Hi, I wrote a working example as the `## Updates` part, which you can see it's working without explicit cast or sth, and yet it has a demerit that every possible return code is needed at result definition like `Result<...codes, APIResult>`. Is this the solution that you would prefer?

Comment: @Ryuujo - I defer to your preference, whatever that may be.